# Admob : Aborting last ad request since another ad request is already in progress

Tags: android, admob

interstitial Ad is only loading once on android 5.0 or higher then LogCat I get those warnings:

Aborting last ad request since another ad request is already in progress. The current request object will still be cached for future refreshes.
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You should only call `loadAd` on an interstitial:

1. when you first create it
2. after you have shown an ad